# No se muestra el contenido real en el código fuente al trabajar con AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html5, ajax

Estoy trabajando con `HTML5`, `PHP` y `JQuery` junto con `AJAX`. Dentro de un formulario tengo 5 `input type="radio"` el cual hace cambiar el contenido de la página en un `div` según cual se seleccione. Los mismos se llaman "Todas", "Informática", "Redes", "Multimedia" y "BD/Programación". Se trata de un glosario y el contenido a mostrar son los términos que corresponden según el input seleccionado. Es una manera de mostrarle al usuario un listado (ordenado por abecedario) de todos los términos que hay en el glosario.

Por defecto, **cuando se carga la página, el contenido arranca con el que dice "Todas"** (el cual trae todos los términos que están en las otras cuatro secciones: *Informática*, *Redes*, *Multimedia* y *BD/Programación*, o sea, todos). El usuario, como se daran cuenta, puede filtrar el contenido al seleccionar secciones; por ejemplo, **si selecciona "Redes" sólo traerá los términos que hay en dicha sección** y así con las demás categorías.

Todo esto anda casi perfecto, no refresca toda la página al utilizar `AJAX` y además el contenido se muestra al usuario de manera correcta. El problema es al querer ver el código fuente de la página (*Ctrl+u*). Siempre me muestra lo mismo. **Me refiero a que en ese código fuente los términos que se ven son los que se buscaron en el principio, el que estaba seleccionado por defecto (input que dice "Todas")**.

Por ejemplo: si selecciono el input que tiene "Redes", en la página se muestra bien todos los términos que corresponden a esa categoría, **pero si quiero ver el código fuente, allí se ve otra cosa distinta**. Se ven los mismos términos de cuando se cargó la página por primera vez (input de "Todas"). Ya he intentado de vaciar el div con `$(".Secc").empty()` y también hacer un *load* con `$('.Secc').load();` pero no pasa nada, además el `load()` me duplica la página.

En realidad, no me importaría si no tendría que usar esos términos que se ven en la página para algo más, pero si los debo usar para algo más. Es que esos términos se muestran como enlaces (`<a class="GloIT" href="ActiveX" title="ActiveX">ActiveX</a>`, `<a class="GloIT" href="Fragmentar" title="Fragmentar">Fragmentar</a>`, `<a class="GloIT" href="SDRAM" title="SDRAM">SDRAM</a>`...) y los mismos van a cambiar según la sección que elija el usuario. Y cuando se hace clic en algún de estos enlaces el mismo debe mostrar la definición de ese término en la categoría correspondiente. Por eso es importante que se muestren bien, tanto en la página cómo en el código fuente.

Acá les paso el código que tengo, el cual está todo en la misma página (el `formulario`, lo de `PHP` y lo de `JQuery`) la cual se llama `TerminosIT.php`:

```
  <form id="frRadio" method="post" action="">
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Selección por secciones: </legend>
     <label for="radio-1">Todas</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" value="0">
     <label for="radio-2">Informática</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2" value="1">
     <label for="radio-3">Redes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-3" value="2">
     <label for="radio-4">Multimedia</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-4" value="3">
     <label for="radio-5">BD/Programación</label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-5" value="4">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

En `PHP` tengo:

```
<div class="Secc">
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['radio'])){ 
    $Sel=$_POST['radio'];
    switch($Sel){ 
        case 0:
            Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
            break;
        case 1:
            Informatica($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
            break;
        case 2:
            Redes($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
            break;
        case 3:
            Multimedia($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
            break;
        case 4:
            Programacion($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
            break;
    }// end switch
}else{Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);}?>
</div>
```

El `<div class="Secc">` es donde se va a ir mostrando todo. No sé si vale la pena poner el código que tiene cada función que está dentro de cada `case` en `PHP`. Pero allí básicamente, por medio de `MySQL`, busca en las tablas correspondientes los términos para mostrarlos luego dentro del tag `<a...>...</a>`.

Y por último lo de `JQuery`:

```
$(function() {
    $("input").checkboxradio();
    $("#radio-1").attr("checked","checked").change();
     $("input").on("change", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //$(".Secc").hide();
        $(".Secc").empty();
        var dataString = $("#frRadio").serialize() + '&' + encodeURI("radio")+ '='+ encodeURI($("input[name$='radio']:checked").val());
         $.ajax({
            url: "TerminosIT.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                //$(".Secc").show();
                var $response = $.parseHTML(data);
                $response = $('.Secc', $response).html();
                $(".Secc").html($response);
                }
            });
        return false;
     });
  });
```

En conclusión, **en el código fuente siempre se ve lo mismo (lo que se cargo la primera vez)**. Quizás sea un tema de `AJAX` y no tenga solución. De no tener solución voy a tener que hacerlo, aunque no me gustaría, sin utilizar `AJAX` y recargar todo la página cuando se seleccione algunos de los `checkboxradio`. A lo mejor saben de otra forma mejor.

**Alternativa**: A lo mejor lo puedo arreglar agregando ciertos atributos al tag `<a>` desde `JQuery`. Es que por ejemplo, cuando se selecciona la sección "Redes" me quedan los enlaces de esta manera `<a class="GloIT" href="IP" data-id="2" data-seccion="Redes" title="IP">IP</a>`, en "Multimedia" `<a class="GloIT" href="CD" data-id="3" data-seccion="Multimedia" title="CD">CD</a>`, etc. Agregando esos `data-` según corresponda

Pero como ya dije en el código fuente me lo pone así `<a class="GloIT" href="IP" title="IP">IP</a>`, `<a class="GloIT" href="CD" title="CD">CD</a>` esto es sin los `data-`, porque al seleccionar "Todas" esos `data-` no van y que sólo se agregan cuando se elige cualquiera de las otras cuatro secciones ("Informática", "Redes", "Multimedia" y "BD/Programación").

Entonces, como lo que me interesa aquí es el `data-id` y el `data-seccion`, podría por intermedio de un `switch{...}` (para saber en qué sección trabajar) y un `for`, recorrer todos los tag (`<a>` que tengan sólo la `class="GloIT"`) e ir agregando esos atributos (`data-`) y quitarlos si se selecciona "Todas". ¿Alguien sabe cómo podría realizar eso desde JQuery? ¿Es posible algo así?

Comment: No logro entender cuál es tu problema. Tampoco entiendo por qué si estás usando Ajax usas también *del lado de Ajax* código de servidor (PHP) ¿?. Lo que parece que tienes es una confusión sobre cómo funciona Ajax realmente. ¿? Aquí, `url: "TerminosIT.php"` deberías llamar a un archivo distinto (no a `TerminosIT.php`) que te procese los datos en el servidor, te los devuelva y luego en la parte del `success` cambias lo que tengas que cambiar, sin refrescar la página.

Comment: En lugar de ver código fuente. Tenés que usar "Inspect" y ahi vas a ver el DOM y en todo caso usar el tab de Debug para ver que pasa con la ejecución de javascript.

Comment: El Ctrl+U no te muestra una versión actualizada del DOM, si no que te muestra el estado del DOM en el momento que se sirvió la página. Por lo que cualquier cambio vía AJAX que se haya realizado no lo vas a poder ver.

Comment: Al parecer no se puede realizar entonces. Voy a editar la pregunta, para ver si me ayudan con otra alternativa que se me ocurrio.

Comment: Bueno al final lo de @A.Cedano me dio una idea de separar los archivos y haciendo un par de cosas más pude lograr mi objetivo. Ahora como debe ser la parte del servidor no se muestra en el código fuente, pero el funcionamiento que quería lograr se está realizando. Voy a ver si luego pongo el código completo, aunque lo veo muy largo...

Comment: Bienvenido a Ajax. Verás lo fácil que resulta resolver ciertos problemas haciéndolo así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final la solución fue **separar los archivos**. Ahora tengo lo que quiero que se haga desde el servidor `Enlaces.php` y luego el otro archivo que es `TerminosIT.html` (aquí están el formulario con los radios y al final todo el código de `JQuery`).

Acá una parte del código de `Enlaces.php` sin poner que hace cada función:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)){ 
    if (empty($_POST['radio'])) {
        Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
    } else {
        $Sel=$_POST['radio'];
        switch($Sel){ 
            case 0:
                Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
                break;
            case 1:
                Informatica($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
                break;
            case 2:
                Redes($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
                break;
            case 3:
                Multimedia($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
                break;
            case 4:
                Programacion($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);
                break;
        }// end switch
    }
}else{Todas($cxn,$Let,$Band,$Comp);}
?>
```

Y ahora, lo más importante y donde tenía el problema, el archivo `TerminosIT.html`: en la parte del formulario, el div en donde se mostrará el contenido (`<div class="Secc"></div>`) y al final todo el código de `JQuery` que se genera en el evento *"change"* de los inputs seleccionados (los radios):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listado completo de términos</title>
</head>
<form id="frRadio" method="post" action="Include/Enlaces.php">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Selección por secciones: </legend>
        <label for="radio-1">Todas</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-1" value="0">
        <label for="radio-2">Informática</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-2" value="1">
        <label for="radio-3">Redes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-3" value="2">
        <label for="radio-4">Multimedia</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-4" value="3">
        <label for="radio-5">BD/Programación</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio-5" value="4">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div class="Secc"></div>
<body>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("input").checkboxradio();
    $("#radio-1").attr("checked","checked").change();
    $("input").on("change", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var dataString = $("#frRadio").serialize() + '&' + encodeURI("radio")+ '='+ encodeURI($("input[name$='radio']:checked").val());
         $.ajax({
            url: "Include/Enlaces.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var $response = $.parseHTML(data);
                $response = $('.Secc', $response).html();
                }
            })
            .done(function($response) {
                $(".Secc").html($response);
                let linksConDataId = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-id]");
                for (let x=0;x<linksConDataId.length;x++){
                    linksConDataId[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
                        localStorage.setItem("data-id", this.dataset.id);});
                    linksConDataId[x].addEventListener("contextmenu", function() {
                        localStorage.setItem("data-id", this.dataset.id);});
                }
            });
        return false;
     });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Un poco de explicación**: El uso de `$("#radio-1").attr("checked","checked").change();` es porque quiero que mi primer radio (`#radio-1` que sería "Todas") arranque seleccionado, así de esta manera de movida le muestro algo al usuario cuando carga la página. Luego, en `.done` dentro del trabajo con `Ajax` muestro el contenido en el div (`<div class="Secc"></div>`).

Lo que viene después es un código que tuve que poner para mis `data-id` (que utilizo para diferenciar los enlaces) y así de esta manera al seleccionar cada link me lleva a la categoría correspondiente.